# Как реализовать библиотечную strcmp самостоятельно?

Tags: c++

Подскажите что надо отредактировать?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int compstr(char*, char*);
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    char* s1 = "This is name";
    char* s2 = "jhis is thing";
    cout << compstr(s1, s2) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int compstr(char* s, char *ss)
{
    char* abc = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxvz";// алфавит
    char* abcd = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxvz";// второй алфавит
    int count = strlen(abc); // количество букв
    int c1count = count;// cчетчик
    int c2count = count;// cчетчик
    int chislo;
    for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        if(abc == s)
        {
            break;
        }
        abc = abc++;
        c1count--;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        if(abcd == ss)
        {
            break;
        }
        abcd = abcd++;
        c2count--;
    }
    if(c1count > c2count)
    {
        chislo = -1;
    }
    else if(c1count < c2count)
    {
        chislo = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        chislo = 0;
    }
    return chislo;
}
```

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться С или С++. А затем прочитать про то как работать с указателями (для С), или использовать std::string (для C++). В данном коде лучше ничего не редактировать, просто его стереть, и написать новый нормальный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция может быть определена следующим образом, как это показано в этой демонстрационной программе

```
#include <iostream>

int cmpstr( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 ) ++s1, ++s2;

    return ( ( unsigned char )*s1 > ( unsigned char )*s2 ) - 
           ( ( unsigned char )*s1 < ( unsigned char )*s2 );
}    

int main()
{
    const char *s1 = "A";
    const char *s2 = "B";

    std::cout << "cmpstr( s1, s2 ) = " << cmpstr( s1, s2 ) << std::endl;             
    std::cout << "cmpstr( s2, s1 ) = " << cmpstr( s2, s1 ) << std::endl;             
    std::cout << "cmpstr( s1, s1 ) = " << cmpstr( s1, s1 ) << std::endl;             
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
cmpstr( s1, s2 ) = -1
cmpstr( s2, s1 ) = 1
cmpstr( s1, s1 ) = 0
```